# Swift - Populating an array with NSDictionary String data

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsdictionary

I have successfully set up a session to pull json data from a site - it works. However, when I start to populate my array with the data the array is not populating the information. Please help.
Here is my Person class:

```
class Person {
    var name1 = "name"
    var info1 = "info"

    init(name1: String, info1: String) {

        self.name1 = name1
        self.info1 = info1
    }
}
```

Here is my setUpPerson function:

```
func setUpPerson() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.my-sites-jsondata")

    if url != nil {

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let urlError = false

            if error == nil {

                var urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

                var data: NSData = urlContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                do {

                    let jsonObject = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray)!

                    var index1 = 0

                    while index1 < jsonObject.count {

                        var maindata = (jsonObject[index1] as! NSDictionary)

                        var nameA = maindata["Name"] as! String
                        var infoA = maindata["Info"] as! String

                        var data1 = Person(name1: nameA, info1: infoA)

                        self.arrayOfPersons.append(data1)

                        index1++

                    }

                } catch {

                    print(urlError)
                }

            }

        })

        task.resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are instantiating your `arrayOfPersons`?

Comment: If you mean this:     var arrayOfPersons: [Person] = [Person]()    then yes   otherwise I dont know what you mean

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to check.

Comment: Are you sure jsonObject is an array. I strongly believe that's a dictionary. Could you please double check by printing it.

Comment: why do you convert `data` to `NSString` and then back to `NSData`?

Comment: here is what I printed out(I added extra text beforeafter the curly brackets to seperate out the information)... jsonObject-->
(
        {
        Info = "Back Hurts";
        Name = Charles;
    },
        {
        Info = "Playing video games";
        Name = Ty;
    }
)
^^
maindata-->
{
    Info = "Back Hurts";
    Name = Charles;
}
^^
Charles
Back Hurts
got here
jsonObject-->
(
        {
        Info = "Back Hurts";
        Name = Charles;
    },
        {
        Info = "Playing video games";
        Name = Ty;
    }
)
^^
maindata-->
{
    Info = "Playing video games";
    Name = Ty;
}
^^

Comment: vadian - I removed that line of NSData. I'm not sure why I had it in there but the result is still the same now....

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks all good to me.

To me your `self.arrayOfPersons` is also being set (I just tested it with my test app).

You're probably attempting to print it before it's been set in the async `dataTaskWithURL` block.

An async block performs in the background, so as the code written immediately after your block executes on the main thread, the code within the async block will not yet be complete.

To me, the code has definitely executed. But because the async code hasn't finished executing yet, you are not seeing it set.

You will have to wait until after the async code executes before checking for the new value.

You can try like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Set your data on property here
});
```

Comment: I think I understand what you said - but I'm not sure how to fix it? Please let me know.

Comment: You may try setting your data on main thread like I showed in the example.

Comment: I'm sure this is the issue but I'm not sure Where in the code to place the dispatc_async

Comment: Put only array append line in that. As I said I ran my app with your code and it worked fine. Just try that out once please.

Comment: I did this                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            
                            self.arrayOfPersons.append(data1)
                                
                                }      and it saying I need to add a "," but it keeps doing it and many many "," are added and doesn't fix the error

Comment: Sorry - syntax. I was able to get it to run but the app crashed after one loop through the jsonObject...

Comment: O yes, I forgot u r running this in a while loop. BTW... Where are you reading that array when u see it nil?

Comment: Its not showing on the app simulator in the custom table cell

Comment: On the flip side I used a standard call to fill the array and it worked just fine...    var person1 = Person[name1: “Charles”, info1: “back hurts”]
var person2= Person[name1: “Ty”, info1: “playing video games”]
self.arrayOfPersons.append(person1)
self.arrayOfPersons.append(person2)

Comment: It does... I'm pretty sure the asynchronous block timing is the issue here.

Comment: I remember this now from an online course I took but I just dont know how to get the block timing to work out... nothing I try seems to stop the app from crashing

Comment: Although not a good suggestion but can u try once putting entire while loop in that main queue block. We should avoid doing such computations on main thread though. I'm just trying to help you.

Comment: I do not see the code to reloadData on tableView. That's the missing piece here.

Comment: Where would I add that call     self.myTableView.reloadData()  ?

Comment: BTW printing to the logs print(nameA), print(infoA) shows the strings I expect it to show.....   SO FRUSTRATING

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully complete this project. The answer came in two fold...

1. I needed  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`
2. `reloadData()`